# CSS Allow Footer position to override @page .margin-bottom

Tags: html, css, pdf-generation

I am generating a PDF and the content is dynamic. The content may span across 2 pages and when it does the footer is overlapping the content.

I have decided to try and use the following

```
@page
{
    margin-bottom: 150px;
}
```

This is pushing all the page content including the footer up 150px. I was wondering if there was a way to allow the footer container to be un-effected by this bottom margin.

I basically want the footer to fill that 150px gap at the bottom of the page. If I don't use this margin the footer just overlaps the page content and then flows to the next page which is the issue.

[image]

The grey bar is the footer and as you can see the text is overlapping it. This screenshot has also got the margin-bottom applied so I want to move the footer down to fill that gap.

Comment: Can you please provide a Fiddle or test case?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like quite the challenge! What you need is a ["sticky footer"](https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/sticky-footer/). Use flexbox. This code tells the parent to be 100vh of the page, and the child element to fill the remaining space.